# On the density of a particular subset of integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, arithmetic-functions

Given a positive integer $n$ in the standard form
$$n=\prod_k p_k^{\alpha_k}$$
and the arithmetic function (investigated by Erdős in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-71/issue-2/On-an-additive-arithmetic-function/pjm/1102811427.full))
$$A(n)=\sum_k \alpha_k p_k$$
let's define the subset $E$ of positive integers
$$E=\Big\{n\in N:A(n)\,|\,n,\;A(n)\lt n\Big\}=\Big\{16,27,30,60,70,72,84,105,150,\dots\Big\}$$
**I ask if the density of this subset has ever been studied and, in particular, if it is possible to prove the convergence of the series**
$$\sum_{n\,\in\,E}\frac 1 n$$
After $10^6$ terms ($n=1507900211$) the sum of the series is $0.367044640179285...$, the growth being extremely slow.

Primes and semiprimes do not belong to the subset $E$, but composites of the forms (and many others)
$$2^{2^k}p(p+2^{2^k})$$
(with $p$, $p+2^{2^k}$ primes and $k\ge0$)
$$p^{(p-1)q}q^p$$
(with $p$, $q$ primes)

are in $E$.

[ Question [also asked on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4383997/on-the-density-of-a-particular-subset-of-integers) ]

Comment: A user on math.se has commented on the value calculated out to $10^9$.

Comment: Doesn't theorem 2.1 in the paper linked in the question handle the cardinality?

Comment: The values you gave seem to show that the $k$-th smallest element of $E$ is greater than the $k$-th smallest half sum of twin primes. Could this be proven, that would entail the convergence of your series.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN nice idea, but this is definitely out of reach, as it would need (or imply) the twin prime conjecture to be proven :)